# How to copy cells downwards without overwriting what's under it?

Tags: excel, vba

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/copydown.xlsx

This is the sheet if you can't view dropbox.
[image]

This is the workbook. What I'm looking to do is where it shows 3M, copy the title of the company down to where it shows Total in Column A, and do the same with the next company.

How do I do this in Excel VBA? I know I can use the last row, but it's not exactly the best way for this I believe, because the original version will have over 300 different companies.

Here is the original code I am using for now. Without the extra bits added in.

Option Explicit

```
Sub Import()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wsIMP As Worksheet 'Import
    Dim wsTOT As Worksheet 'Total
    Dim wsSHI As Worksheet 'Shipped
    Dim wsEST As Worksheet 'Estimate
    Dim wsISS As Worksheet 'Issued
    Dim Shift As Range


    Set wsIMP = Sheets("Import")
    Set wsTOT = Sheets("Total")
    Set wsSHI = Sheets("Shipped")
    Set wsEST = Sheets("Estimate")
    Set wsISS = Sheets("Issued")

    With wsIMP

        wsIMP.Range("E6").Cut wsIMP.Range("E5")
        wsIMP.Range("B7:G7").Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Matt, you say where it shows total.  What row would that be for 3M. 5 or 6? And what should be in A7?

Comment: `where it shows Total in Column A` it doesn't show Total in Column A. But if I can surmise what you mean, try the `FillDown` method in VBA. You can loop backwards through your list and set your `FillDown` range to be only the appropriate rows that match column B.

Comment: Sorry... what I mean is the 3M in Column A will be coppied down till 5 Wits is. Then 5 Wits will be copied down till the next company, etc...

Comment: yes, very good. See `Range.FillDown` and my first comment about looping.

Comment: I hate to ask  this, but how? I've been looking online for an explination on how to use FillDown, but it seems everyone plus their mother seems to have an answer on how to make it work without actually showing how to make it work...

Comment: You don't need VBA for this: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/enter-data-into-many-cells-at-once/

Comment: @DougGlancy I do for what needs to be done. This is only going to be one part of a much larger script I have working now. This is going to be given to someone to use. After this part is done I am going to be moving sections to three other tabs because of other information that you don't see.

Comment: Select the whole range to be filled (including all the company names). Then GoTo>Special>Blanks .  That should select only the blank cells. In A2 enter =A1 and then Ctrl+Enter to enter that in the whole selected range.  That's from memory but I think that will do what you need.  EDIT - Doug beat me to it...

Comment: @TimWilliams Again, I know this, but I am asking how to make this work using VBA, because when I give this over to a person they will be entering data to do something very specific each week. This data is going to change. I need the VBA equivilant of doing it manually.  Otherwise I never would of asked and I would of been doing this already.  Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Would AutoFill be a better function for my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt, I had a great function for this a few months back, but I forgot to copy into my library. However, I've done a pretty good mock-up of what I had before. (I was using it to fill down entries in a pivot table for some reason or other).

Anyway, here it is. You may need to tweak it to meet your exact needs, and I am not claiming it's not prone to any errors at the moment, but it should be a great start.

**EDIT** = I've updated my code post to integrate into yours to make it easier for you.

```
    Sub Import()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wsIMP As Worksheet, wsTOT As Worksheet 'Total
    Dim wsSHI As Worksheet, wsEST As Worksheet 'Estimate
    Dim wsISS As Worksheet, Shift As Range


    Set wsIMP = Sheets("Import")
    Set wsTOT = Sheets("Total")
    Set wsSHI = Sheets("Shipped")
    Set wsEST = Sheets("Estimate")
    Set wsISS = Sheets("Issued")

    With wsIMP

        .Range("E6").Cut .Range("E5")
        .Range("B7:G7").Delete xlShiftUp

        Call FillDown(.Range("A1"), "B")

        '-> more code here

    End With


End Sub

Sub FillDown(begRng As Range, col As String)

Dim rowLast As Long, rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range

rowLast = Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngStart = begRng

Do

    If rngStart.End(xlDown).Row < rowLast Then
        Set rngEnd = rngStart.End(xlDown).Offset(-1)
    Else
        Set rngEnd = Cells(rowLast, rngStart.Column)
    End If

    Range(rngStart, rngEnd).FillDown
    Set rngStart = rngStart.End(xlDown)

Loop Until rngStart.Row = rowLast


End Sub

enter code here
```

Comment: Matt, the code you've now put in your OP seems to have nothing to do with your question. All it does is cut some data and delete some rows. I can see in that code you are missing a `End With` statement, that will definitely cause an error! However, I don't know what error you are getting since you didn't specify.

Comment: It does, I showed what needed to be shown, the other bit has prices, shipping information, addresses, dates, etc, stuff that can't be made public.. that is what the rest of the code is taking care of, it's for formatting.

Comment: Run-time error '1004': FillDown method of Range calss failed.

Comment: Did you adjust the code to meet your specific data set and sheet name? Also, what is the address of the `Range(rngStart, rngEnd)` when you get the error?

Comment: I got the error `Range(rngStart, rngEnd).FillDown` there, it seems it didn't like it for some reason.

Comment: I know that is where you got the error. The question is how to debug it? I know the error is most likely caused by a "bad" range, so look at what the actual Range is for `Range(rngStart, rngEnd)` and that will tell you what the problem is. I suspect it's not getting filled properly based on how your data is set up and how the code is written.

Comment: I tried to debug it shift-F8 and it's showing nothing... so I'm stuck... sorry...

Comment: `Shift+F8` will step over your code line, not help you debug in this sense. What you need to do is type `Debug.Print Range(rngStart, rngEnd).Address` right before the this line `Range(rngStart, rngEnd).FillDown` then look in the Immediate Window for the result. Alternatively, you can type `?Range(rngStart, rngEnd).Address` in the Immediate Window (CTRL + G) to see it as well. Once you have this, you can back into why that range was chosen and figure out what it should be and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Same error... I'm sorry, but that is all the code is telling me, and that is with the `Debug.Print Range(rngStart, rngEnd)`. in there where you told me to put it.  After I press Debug all that is highlighted is `Range(rngStart, rngEnd).FillDown`

Comment: Try this, ignore the `Debug.Print...` Make sure your `rngStart` and `rngEnd` are valid. See what those values are. Try `Msgbox rngStart.Address ` & `Msgbox rngEnd.Address` or hover over them and see if they produce an error. Matt, you would serve yourself GREATLY! to take 30 minutes and read up on how to debug code in VBA. It will save you many back and forths like this.

Comment: You can also post a link to your data set, because based on what you gave me this code works flawlessly.

Comment: Sure, here... https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/copydown.xlsx It was in the OP.

Comment: This the exact data set i built the code off. You need to provide the code as you are using or there is nothing I can do to help. What i built works perfectly on this data set. Otherwise, hover see my last comment.

Comment: The code I gave you in the OP was it. Just change the tab name to Import, that was all the code I had written at the time. I've updated the sheet again. I have rows going into other tabs based off of sections you can't see... right now I am only giving the code that relates to the issue at hand, which is moving things, and then wanting to copy the first part of A down till the next filled row, then copying that down, etc, etc, etc...

Comment: The rest of the code I have has things moving to other tabs based off of things you can't see so it won't make any sense to you.

Comment: Okay, well the only other thing I can offer is make sure the sheet you want to do FillDown is active when you run the code. Otherwise, check the values of `rngStart` and `rngEnd` as they are populated. THis will tell you if you are getting the range you expect or not. If it's not giving you what you expect, you'll need to adjust the code.

Comment: I also updated my code above to integrate your code. Maybe this will help you understand it more?

Comment: Only thing I don't see is where this actually copys only what is in column A, and not anywhere else...

Comment: Ok, just checked out the code again, and I'm still getting the same error. When I look at rgnStart, it is at the beginning on A1, the rngStart.End, is A2, and the (x1Down) is -4121, which means it's not even getting to A7 to do what is needed by the sounds of it.

Comment: The `.Range("A1")` in `Call FillDown(.Range("A1"), "B")` sets the starting point for the FillDown. In the FillDown Sub it knows to only copy column A, or whatever range you give it. Could be more columns, if you like.

Comment: but it's not, that's the problem. Do I need to put this down to A7 to make this work or is that irrelivant?

Comment: I just downloaded your link again... And look at that...  **the structure of your data set changed!!!** Matt, it's very frustrating to find this out at THIS point! Especially when I mentioned that you may need to tweak the code to get your particular data set to work with it. Just change the reference from `.Range("A1")` to the real place you want to start, which is now `.Range("A7")` So the first argument in the sub calls for the cell where you want to start the fill down from, not just the column you want to start on the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are no formulas you don't want to overwrite...

**EDIT** - updated to set original range based off end of column B

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim sht as WorkSheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    With sht.Range(sht.Range("A7"), _
                   sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1))

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        .Value = .Value

    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: There are no formulas, just company names... as shown in the OP... so this wouldn't work in my case I think. Good idea though... because as far as I can tell this will only work with if you have a small section to edit... not several groupings like I do.

Comment: The column is always going to be the same, the range on the cells filled are always going to change month to month. There is nothing in your script that I can see that will take the first of what is in column A and copy it down using column B as a refrence till when the end of column B ends... then loop again... does this make sense now?

Comment: Matt, your question doesn't say anything about Column B, nor is there any indication of where "Total" is in Column A. Care to add a bit more detail?

Comment: Basically I need the names in Column A to copy down till the end of comumn B, and then repeat when a new name shows up, repeat and rinse.  This ultimately will be changed to another column to refrence, but this is all I can show due to NDAs etc...

Comment: The "end of column B" for that Company, or the end of all content on Column B?  It might help to update your question with an "after" screenshot.  Feels like we're all working at cross-purposes here.

Comment: Re-download the original link, I've updated the sheet, but basically what I'm looking for is for for the 3M company to be copied down till right before the next company name, then the next company name to be copied down till the next company, etc, etc, etc... the thing is the range will change sometimes on a daily basis, so I can't give just a range... because there really isn't one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15772/discussion-between-matt-ridge-and-tim-williams)